# Django fails in server

Tags: python, django, heroku, pip, requirements.txt

I fail to see what is happening.
I put the output of `git push heroku master` for analysis.
When I do `pip freeze > requirements.txt`, it produces a very large file and I do not know if that's normal.

The app locally and in development mode works perfectly.

The Procfile is:
`web: gunicorn losbarkitos.wsgi --log-file -`

The resulting "requirements.txt" is as follows (I think it is too long):

```
gunicorn==19.3.0
macholib==1.5.1
matplotlib==1.3.1
modulegraph==0.10.4
numpy==1.8.0rc1
pip-tools==0.3.5
py2app==0.7.3
pyOpenSSL==0.13.1
pyobjc-core==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-Accounts==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-AddressBook==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-AppleScriptKit==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-AppleScriptObjC==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-Automator==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-CFNetwork==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-Cocoa==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-Collaboration==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-CoreData==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-CoreLocation==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-CoreText==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-DictionaryServices==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-EventKit==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-ExceptionHandling==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-FSEvents==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-InputMethodKit==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-InstallerPlugins==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-InstantMessage==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-LatentSemanticMapping==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-LaunchServices==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-Message==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-OpenDirectory==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-PreferencePanes==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-PubSub==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-QTKit==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-Quartz==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-ScreenSaver==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-ScriptingBridge==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-SearchKit==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-ServiceManagement==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-Social==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-SyncServices==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-SystemConfiguration==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-WebKit==2.5.1
pyparsing==2.0.1
python-dateutil==1.5
pytz==2013.7
scipy==0.13.0b1
six==1.4.1
vboxapi==1.0
virtualenv==1.11.6
wsgiref==0.1.2
xattr==0.6.4
zope.interface==4.1.1
```

I do not understand, it works fine in local but when I up the app fails.

Comment: What is the problem? You have to give us more information in order to figure out what is happening?

Comment: I don't understand what you're showing us with that output. The requirements.txt is supposed to be committed to git and uploaded to Heroku, so that it knows what to install. And you don't actually seem to have installed Django.

Comment: Currently, the repository upload to heroku and pluck in development mode and everything works fine. 
When I change the wsgi file to start in production, the server starts up and then drops

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem was in the virtualenv that had conflicts. That is solved but now when I make DeploIT on Heroku have this problem:

2015-03-20T14: 12: 49.559524 + 00: 00 heroku [api]: Deploy fca806a by chus@chusito.es
2015-03-20T14: 12: 49.559524 + 00: 00 heroku [api]: Release V111 created by chus@chusito.es
2015-03-20T14: 12: 50.164102 + 00: 00 heroku [site.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-03-20T14: 13: 01.937982 + 00: 00 heroku [site.1]: Starting process command `gunicorn losbarkitos With: app --log-file = -`
2015-03-20T14: 13: 05.027025 + 00: 00 app [site.1]: bash: gunicorn: command not found
2015-03-20T14: 13: 05.962874 + 00: 00 heroku [site.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-03-20T14: 13: 05.962046 + 00: 00 heroku [site.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-03-20T14: 13: 05.952810 + 00: 00 heroku [site.1]: Process exited with status 127
2015-03-20T14: 13: 18.780423 + 00: 00 heroku [site.1]: Starting process command `gunicorn losbarkitos With: app --log-file = -`
2015-03-20T14: 13: 20.206266 + 00: 00 app [site.1]: bash: gunicorn: command not found
2015-03-20T14: 13: 20.962180 + 00: 00 heroku [site.1]: Process exited with status 127
2015-03-20T14: 13: 21.002937 + 00: 00 heroku [site.1]: State changed from starting to crashed

That is, it seems as if I did not acknowledge gunicorn.